# how to manage [object HTMLDivElement] and get its content?

Tags: javascript

I have saved an array in local storage and trying to use it but when I console.log the `localstorage.getitem` it returns 
 `[object HTMLDivElement]`  I have tried to use `.innerhtml` or [...] on it but they didn't work. Btw, since it's an array, I have to use `JSON.stringify(movieWatchlistArray)`:

```
 localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(movieWatchlistArray))
 let str =localStorage.getItem("key")
 console.log(JSON.parse(str) )
```

But when I do this, it will return an empty object inside an array while when I console.log  the original array it's fine  so I tried to do it without JSON part, it worked but returns a string  of 
`[object HTMLDivElement]`

```
 localStorage.setItem("key",movieWatchlistArray)  
 let str =localStorage.getItem("key")
 console.log(str)
```

So how to get the content of `[object HTMLDivElement]` I have used `.innerhtml` but it says can't use `.innerHTML` on undefined .

Comment: Why are you storing the entire elements inside localStorage? Do you need to put it back on the DOM when you read from it?

Comment: It's a watchlist going to render all of the movies back when it's being clicked.

Comment: do you have any suggestions? or maybe another way of handling it? @Hanlet Escaño

Comment: You should save the `.outerHTML` of the element you wish to save to localStorage... Instead of the element itself.

Comment: going to test it

Comment: that's right instead of selecting the element should select the`.outerHTML` so should I delete this question?  or please write an answer so I can accept it you can give a brief talk about  [object HTMLDivElement] .thank you in advance.

Comment: You will see [object HTMLDivElement] when Javascript has to convert certain objects to strings. Local storage only takes strings so it has to do this. If you want to store the object you will need to convert the data in the object into a string somehow (e.g., JSON). It would be better if you do not store your data in the DOM at all and instead serialize some sort of model object into local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you trying to save an element in localstorage you should save the `.outerHTML` of it, not the element itself. although it's not recommended to save the whole HTML in local storage instead save the data as an object and use it in js to render the HTML.
so in this case it will be  :

```
movieWatchlistArray.unshift(document.querySelector(`.movie--${moviePageNumber-1}`).outerHTML)
```

Comment: thank you all for the comments it's a summary of the useful things you said.